# how to enable audit framework in arch linux 3.12 kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, monitoring, audit, archlinux

I want to use [audit framework](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework) on my latest arch linux, but running `sudo auditctl -w /home/` in console gives me

`Error - audit support not in kernel
 Cannot open netlink audit socket`

I tried to enable of course audit via kernel boot params setting audit flag: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet audit=1"` but nothing changes after reboot, still the same error.

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Can you see `"audit=1"` in `/proc/cmdline` in booted kernel?

Comment: yes, `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=59c7ed3d-5c1a-464e-8da0-6bcf76bc19d2 rw quiet audit=1`, also there's a mistake, I have 3.18.2 kernel.

Comment: audit=      [KNL] Enable the audit sub-system
            Format: { "0" | "1" } (0 = disabled, 1 = enabled)
            0 - kernel audit is disabled and can not be enabled
                until the next reboot
            unset - kernel audit is initialized but disabled and
                will be fully enabled by the userspace auditd.
            1 - kernel audit is initialized and partially enabled,
                storing at most audit_backlog_limit messages in
                RAM until it is fully enabled by the userspace
                auditd.

Comment: May be you also need to set `audit_backlog_limit=` in cmd line.

Comment: audit_backlog_limit= [KNL] Set the audit queue size limit.
            Format: <int> (must be >=0)
            Default: 64

Comment: don't think so, because even getting this value via `sudo auditctl -s` gives me `Error - audit support not in kernel`

Comment: Recompile kernel with audit support then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recompile a kernel using ABS to get audit support. 
You will need to add `CONFIG_AUDIT=y` in the config file before `makepkg -s`.

P.S. Compilation might take very long.

Comment: Yes, I did just what you suggested, with ABS arch linux kernel compilation tool, thx. I just forgot about this question, and didn't answer it by myself. Anyway, audit framework gave me too bad performance on my machine, so I vanished using it.

Comment: I was trying to do that in order to use e4rat. i